# How do I calculate a mean from a subset?

Tags: r

I am new to R so my title might not even make sense. Basically, I have this data set, which is the length of insects collected at 2 different sites. When I used the 'summary' function, I got values for both sites, and I'd like to do calculate the mean of each site:

```
> ls()
[1] "simulies"
> ls.str()
simulies : 'data.frame':        615 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Site  : Factor w/ 2 levels "Lovering","Orford": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Length: num  4.1 2.8 2.2 3.2 3.2 3.1 3.1 4.1 4.1 3.2 ...
> summary(simulies)
   Site         Length     
Lovering:398   Min.   :0.600  
Orford  :217   1st Qu.:1.300  
               Median :1.600  
               Mean   :2.034  
               3rd Qu.:2.700  
               Max.   :5.000
```

Comment: Using just base R one can use the tapply function: `tapply(simulies, simulies$Site, FUN=mean)`

Comment: Well, in base that would be `tapply(simulies$Length, simulies$Site, FUN = mean)`. Ben, I see you edited your question - are you having trouble applying the answers from the dupe to your own case? Or are you good?

Comment: Yes I was trying to refer to the duplicate and it didn't work either. However, I got some help in the comments below, I was missing the capital S in "Site".

Answer (score 0):

There are many different options. Two of them:

To get the mean of one site:

```
mean(simulies$Length[simulies$Site=="Lovering"])
```

Or using ddply to get output for both sites:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(simulies, .(Site), summarize, Mean=mean(Length))
```

Comment: For the first option, I get [1] NaN

Comment: I updated my answer becuase I noticed that Site should have a capital letter. It should work now.

Comment: Now it works!Thank you.